# Use of conjunctive adverb with participle clause

Tags: participle-clauses

I have written a sentence by using participle clause

> Any contribution cannot be erased from the mind, therefore being essential for being successful

But my teacher is saying that "*therefore being essential for being successful*" is not correct.

I have read that I can connect two sentences together having the same subjects:

1. Any contribution cannot be erased from the mind
2. Therefore, any contribution is essential for being successful

So to me, my sentence was correct since the two sentences had the same subjects. I suppose that using a conjunctive adverb like 'therefore', 'hence', or 'thus' with the participle clause can be a reason for him to mark this incorrect. Am I right?

Comment: Even in the sentence that you suggrst as an alternative, using "any contribution" twice, it is not clear what you are trying to state. Can you provide some context and/or explanation?

Comment: Please, please fix your punctuation. Also, check your grammar. Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to see what the point is of keeping around such an incomprehensible question. It is far more likely to confuse than help.

Answer (score 1):

> [A]ny contribution cannot be erased from the mind, therefore being essential for being successful.

This is unnatural.

You could try

> Any contribution cannot be erased from the mind and therefore **is** essential for **success**.

This means

> Any contribution **cannot be** erased from the mind.

> Any contribution **is** essential for success.

The verbs are parallel, unlike the use of *being*.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the lack of context, it took me a very long time to determine what you were trying to say:

> Any contribution cannot be erased from the mind, (the contribution) therefore being essential for being successful

This might be correct, I'm not sure. Certaintly awkward. An idiomatic way to say this is:

> **Any contributions, then, cannot be forgotten, rendering them essential for success.**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the conjunctive adverb *therefore*; it is the use of the word *being* in a participle clause.  When you use the form "being + adjective" at the beginning of a participle clause, it is used to replace *because/since/as*.

> Any contribution cannot be erased from the mind, therefore being essential for being successful.

> Any contribution cannot be erased from the mind, therefore because it is essential for being successful.

> Any contribution cannot be erased from the mind, therefore as it is essential for being successful.

> Any contribution cannot be erased from the mind, therefore since it is essential for being successful.

Do you see how *therefore* collides with the because/as/since wording?  Now try it without the word "therefore".

> Any contribution cannot be erased from the mind, because it is essential for being successful.

We should remove the comma in this version, but use the *being* form and it becomes correct:

> Any contribution cannot be erased from the mind, being essential for being successful.

Using *being* twice in the same clause is wordy and awkward.  It might be better as:

> Any contribution cannot be erased from the mind, being essential for success.

If you want to convey the sense of the continuous tense instead, there are many ways to do that.  For example:

> Any contribution cannot be erased from the mind, being essential for lasting success.